# Объединение sql запросов в один класс JDBC

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

Для подключения к бд и работы с ней использую две библиотеки [commons dbutils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) и [commons dbcp2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) (пул подключений к бд).

Есть три класса в которых прописаны запросы к бд. Все эти классы отвечают за свой функционал (не просто так разделил)^

DataBaseUser

```
public class DataBaseUser {

    private QueryRunner queryRunner;

    public DataBaseUser(BasicDataSource basicDataSource) {
        this.queryRunner = new QueryRunner(basicDataSource);
    }

    ...
}
```

DataBaseAdmin

```
public class DataBaseAdmin {

    private QueryRunner queryRunner;

    public DataBaseAdmin(BasicDataSource basicDataSource) {
        this.queryRunner = new QueryRunner(basicDataSource);
    }

    ...
}
```

DataBaseChat

```
public class DataBaseChat {

    private QueryRunner queryRunner;

    public DataBaseChat(BasicDataSource basicDataSource) {
        this.queryRunner = new QueryRunner(basicDataSource);
    }

    ...
}
```

Как видно конструктор у всех один, но методы разные (дубликатов нет).

Хотелось бы создать один класс который бы смог получить доступ ко всем методам этих трех классов. Как правильно такое сделать? сделать класс обертку который в себе будет хранить все три класса? или как.

Еще. использование этих классов сейчас выглядит таким образом:

```
BasicDataSource basicDataSource = Core.getDataSource();

DataBaseAdmin dbAdmin = new DataBaseAdmin(basicDataSource);
DataBaseChat dbChat = new DataBaseChat(basicDataSource);

...

basicDataSource.getConnection().close();
```

Тут я беру `DataSource` который предоставляет библиотека `dbcp2` передаю в `QuerryRunner` который их `DbUtils`. Он же в свою очередь берет подключение из пула. В последней строке возвращаю подключение в пул свободных.

Comment: Уточните для начала для чего необходимо "получить доступ ко всем методам этих трех классов" и уже от этого можно советовать.

Comment: @ezhov_da что бы использовать один класс вместо двух-трех как в примере.

Comment: А эти классы по отдельности юзаются???

Comment: @JVic да. в конце поста пример использования привел.

Comment: @Tsyklop в конце поста я увидел только пример использования но не увидел всего контекста; Вы используете эти классы по отдельности в разных контекстах? Например в каком-то классе у вас вообще нет `DataBaseChat`

Comment: @JVic Верно....

Answer (score 0):

Именно так "сделать класс обертку который в себе будет хранить все три класса":

```
    class BusinessLogic {
        private BasicDataSource basicDataSource;
        private DataBaseUser dataBaseUser;
        private DataBaseAdmin dataBaseAdmin;
        private DataBaseChat dataBaseChat;

        public BusinessLogic(
                BasicDataSource basicDataSource,
                DataBaseUser dataBaseUser,
                DataBaseAdmin dataBaseAdmin,
                DataBaseChat dataBaseChat) {
            this.basicDataSource = basicDataSource;
            this.dataBaseUser = dataBaseUser;
            this.dataBaseAdmin = dataBaseAdmin;
            this.dataBaseChat = dataBaseChat;
        }

        public doLogic() {
            //DO MY LOGIC
            basicDataSource.getConnection().close(); //не очень хорошо закрывать подключение здесь, так как подключение должно закрываться там, где открывалось
        }
    }
```

Только добавить интерфейсы User, Admin, Chat вместо конкретных классов. И в классе использовать интерфейсы.

```
    class BusinessLogic {
        private BasicDataSource basicDataSource;
        private User user;
        private Admin admin;
        private Chat chat;

        public BusinessLogic(
                BasicDataSource basicDataSource,
                User user,
                Admin dataBaseAdmin,
                Chat dataBaseChat) {
            this.basicDataSource = basicDataSource;
            this.user = user;
            this.admin = admin;
            this.chat = chat;
        }

        public doLogic() {
            //DO MY LOGIC
            basicDataSource.getConnection().close(); //не очень хорошо закрывать подключение здесь, так как подключение должно закрываться там, где открывалось
        }
    }
```